DBeaver not recognizing date value in CSV upload
I'm trying to upload a csv file into Postgresql via DBeaver Community.  The values in the csv file look like this:

When I complete the upload it looks like this in Dbeaver but the column type is varchar and not date.

I also adjusted the importer settings as seen below.  I'm at a loss on how to get this column to upload as a date.


If you are importing into an existing table, I don't think dbeaver will attempt to alter the column type for you. Run alter table your_table alter column the_date_column type date using(the_date_column::date);

@Zegarek I'm not importing into an existing table.  I'm creating a new table with the import.

I see a new table option here. According to this, you should be able to select the data type in column mapping dialog.

I found it.  Many thanks @Zegarek
